# Cross-browser Inconsistent Scrollbars

Tags: jquery, css, cross-browser, scrollbar, internet-explorer-9

I'm having a hard time coming up with the words to describe this problem.

Please see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpJzK/1/) for example code.

This problem stemmed from using a [jQuery plugin](http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2011/01/jquery-selectbox-plugin/)<sup>[1]</sup> to replace `select` elements with something more customizable. Essentially, I want an absolutely positioned div to have a minimum width.

When the list doesn't have a scrollbar, browsers seem to render the div identically.

When the list is too long:

- IE9 adds the scrollbar to the outside of the content area, adding to the minimum width
- all other browsers add the scrollbar to the inside of the content area, maintaining the minimum width, while adding a horizontal scrollbar if necessary.
- IE9 in compatibility mode reverts to displaying the scrollbar similarly to other browsers.

I'd like to be able to render the list the same for all browsers. Ideally I'd like to have a pure CSS solution without any browser hacks or conditional comments.

**[1]** I am in no way affiliated with "abeautifulsite.net"

Comment: Why are you using min-width instead of just width?

Comment: @AR, If an item within the [select box has a very long name](http://jsfiddle.net/SpJzK/2/), I want the drop-down to automatically expand to fit the item, but I also need to prevent the select box from shrinking if a list contains short names.

Answer (score 0):

All browsers handle scroll-bars differently as you've learned.  All different widths and some are already included in the element width even when they're not used where others are added to the element's width when they show up.

With the following jQuery plugin, [**jScrollPane**](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html), you can customize the scroll-bars using CSS.  It's not a perfect solution since you'll lose any default scroll-bars.  But on the plus side, you'll have precise cross-browser control over your element widths.

http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html

Answer (score -1):

This seem to display the same for me in FF 3.6 and IE8, don't have IE9 so can't tell:

```
  #scroll
{
border:  5px  solid #000;
height: 100px;
left:  0;
padding: 10px;
position: absolute;
top:  0;
min-width: 100px;
overflow-y:  scroll;
overflow-x:  visible;
}
```

Comment: This solution still causes issues in IE9.